# Random Freezes on pop!_os based on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nvidia, freeze, pop-os, amd

I've experiencing random freezes on Pop!_os distro (based on Ubuntu 22.04), where the whole system freeze and won't do any thing so I have to force restart.

The frequency of freezes is really random. Sometimes it happens several times a day, sometimes once or twice weekly. but recently it's happening very frequenlty. Also, they happen anytime, while typing on Chrome, or while working with VScode or while the system is idle without any programs open.

Here's the device info:

[image]

I don't know the logs needed for such issue, please let me know and I will edit the question and add them.

Comment: honestly, that could be anything, and I'd guess it's hardware. Have you updated all your system firmware to the latest version?

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: `sudo fwupdmgr get-updates`, check for "Devices with available firmware updates".